# Using union to add a new column to an Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, union

I have two tables one table "A" has this data:

```
123 234 765
589 765 865
876 682 132
```

The other table "B" has one column and one row.

```
999
```

I want to be able to add join the tables so that "B" get appended to "A".
This is my intended goal:

```
123 234 765 999
589 765 865 999
876 682 132 999
```

I though using **union** would work, but apparently I know nothing.

This is what I did:

```
select col1,col2,col3 from A
union
select col4 from B
```

This is the result:

```
ORA-01789: query block has incorrect number of result columns
```

What it the correct way to achieve my objective?

As always, all help gratefully appreciated

Comment: I'd like to add that the reason you get an error is because if you're using a set operator like union all queries need to have the same number of columns.

Comment: Yep, I am now aware of it. I also realize the solution, is a special case. If for instance, my “B” table had two columns , the cross join, as stated, would have provided an incorrect result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a cross join in this case:

```
SELECT a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, b.col4
FROM A a
CROSS JOIN B b
```

This should work assuming `B` really only has one record.

Comment: Woot!!
This worked perfectly,
Thanks for the superfast response
I can go home on time for once.